# multiplicative order in field

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, abelian-groups

Let $\alpha$ be primitive element of GF(7). Then order of $\alpha$ is 6, i.e. $o(\alpha)=6$. Now we know that $\alpha^4$ is not equal to 1, and that  $o(\alpha^4)$ = $\frac{6}{gcd(6,4)}$. This also can be written as $gcd(6,4)=\frac{6}{o(\alpha^4)}$. This means that $\frac{6}{o(\alpha^4)}$ divides 4.

Now we can write $\alpha^4=\alpha^{Q\frac{6}{o(\alpha^4)}}=(\alpha^6)^{\frac{Q}{o(\alpha^4)}}=1$!!

I am getting this confusion. I might be making an error I am not aware of, it will help if you can look over this and point me in the right direction.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the *cyclic-groups* tag, because that's what the question really is about (in a way). No need to add anything to Sammy Black's excellent answer that includes both the general formula for the order of an element in a cyclic group and the sample calculation verifying it in the present case.

Answer (score 2):

You may be making this a bit more complicated than it actually is.  The primitive element $\alpha$ generates a cyclic group of order $6$:
$$
\big\langle \alpha \big\rangle = \big\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^5 \big\} \cong C_6
$$

Now, you seem to be interested in the element $\beta = \alpha^4$ and its order in $GF(7)^\times$.  Look at some powers:
$$
\begin{align}
\beta^2 &= \left( \alpha^4 \right)^2 = \alpha^8 = \alpha^2 \\
\beta^3 &= \beta \beta^2 = \alpha^4 \alpha^2 = \alpha^6 = 1
\end{align}
$$

This explicit calculation shows that
$$
o(\beta) = o(\alpha^4) = 3.
$$

Alternatively, you can arrive at this order by applying the formula:
$$
o(\alpha^4) = \frac{6}{\gcd(6, 4)} = \frac{6}{2} = 3.
$$

Comment: I know that $o(\beta)=3$, but then I also see that I can write this element $\beta=(\alpha^6)^{\frac{Q}{3}}$ which makes it equal to $1.$ I would like to just confirm if the way I have used the theorem that $(x^a)^b=(x^b)^a$ is correct or it might just hold for integers and that is why I get a wrong answer that $\beta=1$.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.  What is $Q$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a subtle error. I understand $GF(7)$ to be a field of size $7$, in which case it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

From Gallian's book, "Contemporary Abstract Algebra", page 75

$\textbf{Theorem 4.2}$ Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group and lek $k$ be a positive integer. Then $<a^k>=<a^{gcd(n,k)}>$ and $|a^k|=\frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$.

This does not mean the element $a^k$ equals $a^{gcd(n,k)}$, rather it means they generate the same subgroup. If we apply the theorem and do the substitutions correctly, we get
$k=6$ and $n=7$, hence 
$$|a^4|=\frac{6}{gcd(6,4)}=3$$.

Therefore, because of your argument which is correct, the element $a^4 \in GF(7)$ seems sketchy. The reason is that there is no element of order $6$ in $\mathbb{Z_7}$. The order of any element divides the order of the group, but we have a group of prime order, so they all have order 1 or 7.

The argument is fine, the original assumption is false and hence the contradiction.

Comment: The finite field $GF(7)$ has underlying *additive* group $\Bbb{Z}_7$.  However, the *multiplicative* group of units $GF(7)^\times = GF(7) \setminus \{ 0 \}$ has $6$ elements, is cyclic, and its generator is the primitive element $\alpha$ that the OP mentions.